# google spring oauth2 client works on local but not on internet

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, google-oauth, spring-oauth2

I am here after pulling some hair out.
The login with google oauth2 works fine in local but failed under public domain.
Here are the logs from both:

```
==== request in local
2022-04-28 17:11:26.080 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
2022-04-28 17:11:26.080 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2022-04-28 17:11:26.080 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[4/0AX4XfWghwFo-03F8JRldcp8xsqSzg31NkVZpHnPqpdXV4hNcTKehChPzrSaTqRVBfh8g4w], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2022-04-28 17:11:26.225 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2022-04-28 17:11:26.225 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] as "application/json;charset=utf-8"
2022-04-28 17:11:26.226 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
2022-04-28 17:11:26.226 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2022-04-28 17:11:26.242 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2022-04-28 17:11:26.242 DEBUG 11004 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"


=====request under public domain
2022-04-28 16:54:05.949 DEBUG 13353 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
2022-04-28 16:54:05.956 DEBUG 13353 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2022-04-28 16:54:05.957 DEBUG 13353 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[4/0AX4XfWjfng4hE-uzmk1CnWgRz922In29TeNs9efZxigfeSaVwvvoCrk-b56rOzFeMEDn0Q], redirect_uri=[https://www.clubspj.com/login/oauth2/code/google]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2022-04-28 16:54:06.064 DEBUG 13353 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

I made sure the url is matching 
[image]

Using this library, version is 2.6.7

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Following are the requests made in order when trying to login with google oauth2

```
GET 302 https://www.clubspj.com/oauth2/authorization/google

GET 200 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=294427952059-ngva8hkoa4cl1af249repefc8lnksl87.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=hiwVEoh6pbzGA4HueQpsF_MydzpyJ5uxnS7FcAoRaKM%3D&redirect_uri=https://www.clubspj.com/login/oauth2/code/google&nonce=3S3BLRPDsdXB6orOGF52YFIHnbyaLLtO8NGjHEDILYo

GET 302 https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent?authuser=0&part=AJi8hANiL7v0LYZsyPvT1Vg6t-K2lzlwtCjwELEoi84mtcyDyjIAhY3FkooOuQ9YwoG10HrQyEv3f4H4ZNN_mVry937SfMm_68H1Zw9ZJfkgRVkPM5aTYsa7jdctKNJWe4I4mEJFxeQ0iqizcZfEXw-COkk3L_3wW1CxL2gwCygMud5-Qv1nDJMblMV1dl2CtaWamt30GyrWoaG_g14mRGLvcmHHruvQD3Uid7t0PI9hNtYYqewJLTdCi6dmn8pLa7MJPqEHdp2nyKJf5YSPqAskAn4BX-_aaLXKeNnQJhC2Cjzpwnux_zKol50e8ymHU5PQpP5hU23lArmBPXU3shEEi4m_yA2R41p8vFaB3f9HpOqp9ThEgMp8nv_po6C7Kk3qLMoWR2COAYvv4zflcA_157vUt6jhDpKoLw2cf7Fbq_4afG1QKiI8x9LOn4iJq6Q2JBh_AxlX9truJZb45fNbDI1nfnrOEQ&as=S-872222817%3A1651179243534195&pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4MtRiws0sgSbs9qRhpREDRpzEWcleEMkDeuoK78Ie-A3UissN40zZ2GdDLIIqoA4P7tjoqyQgVmVDmgmqt8a2qv_ElA-w
GET 302 https://www.clubspj.com/login/oauth2/code/google?state=hiwVEoh6pbzGA4HueQpsF_MydzpyJ5uxnS7FcAoRaKM%3D&code=4%2F0AX4XfWjfng4hE-uzmk1CnWgRz922In29TeNs9efZxigfeSaVwvvoCrk-b56rOzFeMEDn0Q&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=none
```

the last request caused error and redirected to login?error, details of the request:
**Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: https://www.clubspj.com/login?error
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2022 20:54:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Request Header:**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: AWSALBTG=5EB4qie5RCxExuTp2gqDRZuZGDgJBVO8lBlofFhpkZA0J9iQ7JahcSn/jvAmef/eRSL0GALK9P9xcOZgNLSWIwcEEMSRslwigzMPrZQFpQ2pmLPKSx9Apn19TlEENuLOMFmRgG7bbIziTYB+RyqCLZosHMvIIU7Wbcmhsdlz6e1JL9NKYJU=; AWSALBTGCORS=5EB4qie5RCxExuTp2gqDRZuZGDgJBVO8lBlofFhpkZA0J9iQ7JahcSn/jvAmef/eRSL0GALK9P9xcOZgNLSWIwcEEMSRslwigzMPrZQFpQ2pmLPKSx9Apn19TlEENuLOMFmRgG7bbIziTYB+RyqCLZosHMvIIU7Wbcmhsdlz6e1JL9NKYJU=; JSESSIONID=7F3D126AA8A114A2EAB4937EB1A911DA
Host: www.clubspj.com
Referer: https://accounts.google.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36
```

Lastly I am running app on EC2 under elastic IP. Verified that all the JSESSIONID are the same between clubspj.com requests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the little things!
To have google login work in local, you only need `client-id`.
Works as expected after I added the long forgotten `client-secret`.